# Help, I lost the JSON tab in Firebug console

Tags: ajax, json, firebug

From some time (a week before installing the last 1.4.3 update for Firebug) the tab with the JSON contents has disappeared from my Firebug console.

I used to open the GET reply from AJAX in the console, then three tabs appear, which are labelled "URL Parameters", "Headers" and "Reply".

When I clicked on "Reply" another header appeared inside, with more tabs (if I remember well), and one of the tabs was "JSON", showing the JSON array in a readable way. This header has disappeared along with the JSON tab. Anyone know how to get it back? I'm really lost without it.

Answer (score 6):

I eventually figured out why mine wasn't working. It was because my headers were being sent from apache with Content-Type: text/html.

I set the headers with php before printing the JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain')
```

And it all starting working properly - I can now see the JSON tab in the Firebug Console and Net tabs.

Comment: for JSON the headers should be
`header('Content-Type: application/json', true);`

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on Firebug Icon > Options > Reset All Firebug Options.

Comment: Hi Caio, thanks for your answer. 

I tried what you said but right clicking doesn't show any Options menu, only the possibility to clean the console, activate/disactivate panels, activate for all pages and clear some activation list.

I found an Options tab when Firebug is in full screen in View->Options but doesn't seem to be related to my problem.

Comment: I see now the Options you mention should appear in the main menu and I'm not only missing Options but also FBT tracing and Cookies (never had them).

Comment: Hi, Altair.

Looks like Firebug have a related bug about not receiving JSON responses from server. Follow this link, its have a test for the bug I just said: http://www.janodvarko.cz/firebug/tests/1275/Issue1275.htm

Open the Firebug, go to Net > All and just click the button in this page. It worked to me, if it does not work for you, there is a link to the bug page at the same link I sent you.

Regards,
CaioToOn!

Comment: Seems what's happening to me it's different because I don't even have the JSON tab. They are reporting having the contents of that tab destroyed. But yes maybe I will wait for next versions of FF and Firebug. Thanks a lot for your help and interest Caio.

Comment: But have you tried the test at this page? My JSON tab doesn't appear also, only when a JSON request is made. When I clicked the button at the link I sent you, the JSON tab does appear.

Anyway, you're welcome, Altair.

CaioToOn!